# Do GSmartControl Built In Self Tests Work With Modern SSD?

Tags: ssd, smart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a S.M.A.R.T. for Flash Drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/124274/is-there-a-s-m-a-r-t-for-flash-drives)

Does GSmartControl built in SMART tests work with modern SSDs? How can I test a SSD's health? Does Samsung provide a utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMART test that GSmartControl does is not part of the program. The tests are built into the drives themselves. GSmartControl uses a SMART command to tell the drive to test itself. This mean it works on any drive which have the tests built in, which is most of them. If works fine on my Intel SSD at least. It should work for your SSD as well.

Samsung also provides their own SSD utility: Samsung SSD Magician. I do not know if it has some SSD testing capabilities.